# How to deliberately raise Exception in Hive

Tags: exception, hive, hiveql

I wanna raise Exception under certain circumstances, say some `if` or `case` conditions. I'm doing this for returning some `failure` status if certain condition if not satisfied, so I could know and deal with that.

> I have tried several methods but none could raise Exception only under some condition:
>
> 1. **select some column does not exist:** `Exception` is raised when parsing.
> 2. **divide some value by 0:** null is returned, instead of raising `Exception`
> 3. **make some assertation in UDF:** assertations are not allowed in UDF

I wonder if it's possible deliberately Exception to terminate the program.

> e.g. (not legal HiveQL)
>
> SELECT CASE `some_condition` WHEN `true` THEN `continue` ELSE `exception` END AS `condition`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `assert_true` [UDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF), looks like it's exactly what you need.

```
hive> select assert_true (2<1);
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: ASSERT_TRUE(): assertion failed.
Time taken: 0.497 seconds
```

Comment: @Neil it does exit such scripts unless you have `hive.cli.errors.ignore=true` (which is by default set to false). Checked with Hive version 2.1.1.